# I would like to finetune the blip model on ROCO data set for image captioning of chest x-rays

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I want to fine tune the blip model on ROCO database for image captioning chest x-ray images. But I am getting an error regarding integer indexing.

Can anyone please help me understand the cause of the error and how to rectify it.

This is the code:

```
def read_data(filepath,csv_path,n_samples):
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
    images = []
    capts = []
    for idx in range(len(df)):
        if 'hest x-ray' in df['caption'][idx] or 'hest X-ray' in df['caption'][idx]:
            if len(images)>n_samples:
                break            
            else:
                images.append(Image.open(os.path.join(filepath,df['name'][idx])).convert('L'))
                capts.append(df['caption'][idx])
    return images, capts
    

def get_data():
    imgtrpath = 'all_data/train/radiology/images'
    trcsvpath = 'all_data/train/radiology/traindata.csv'
    imgtspath = 'all_data/test/radiology/images'
    tscsvpath = 'all_data/test/radiology/testdata.csv'
    imgvalpath = 'all_data/validation/radiology/images'
    valcsvpath = 'all_data/validation/radiology/valdata.csv'

    print('Extracting Training Data')
    trainimgs, traincapts = read_data(imgtrpath, trcsvpath, 1800)
    
    print('Extracting Testing Data')
    testimgs, testcapts = read_data(imgtrpath, trcsvpath, 100)
    
    print('Extracting Validation Data')
    valimgs, valcapts = read_data(imgtrpath, trcsvpath, 100)


                
    return trainimgs, traincapts, testimgs, testcapts, valimgs, valcapts

def compute_metrics(eval_pred):
    logits, labels = eval_pred
    predictions = np.argmax(logits, axis=-1)
    return metric.compute(predictions=predictions, references=labels)

trainimgs, traincapts, testimgs, testcapts, valimgs, valcapts = get_data() 
model = BlipForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("Salesforce/blip-image-captioning-large")
processor = BlipProcessor.from_pretrained("Salesforce/blip-image-captioning-large")

metric = evaluate.load("accuracy")
traindata = processor(text=traincapts, images=trainimgs, return_tensors="pt", padding=True, truncation=True)
evaldata =  processor(text=testcapts, images=testimgs, return_tensors="pt", padding=True, truncation=True)
training_args = TrainingArguments(output_dir="test_trainer", evaluation_strategy="epoch")
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=traindata,
    eval_dataset=evaldata,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics
)
trainer.train()
```

The code is meant to fine-tune the BLIP model on the ROCO dataset chest x-ray images for the purpose of image captioning.
But when I run it, I am getting this error:

```
  File "C:\Users\omair\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\transformers\feature_extraction_utils.py", line 86, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError("Indexing with integers is not available when using Python based feature extractors")

KeyError: 'Indexing with integers is not available when using Python based feature extractors'
```

Comment: Looks like a problem in your dataset, you should show your `get_data` function

Comment: I have added the functions I am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. You're not providing the labels during training, your `...capts` are passed as the model's "Question". There is an example on how to do that in the link below.
2. Finetuning HF's BlipForConditionalGeneration is not supported at the moment, see https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/finetune-blip-on-customer-dataset-20893/28446 where they just fixed BlipForQuestionAnswering. If you create a dataset based on this link, you will also get the error `ValueError: Expected input batch_size (0) to match target batch_size (511).` which can be solved if you put the effort to reproduce the changes made on BlipForQuestionAnswering to BlipForConditionalGeneration.